# Permanent TCP connection for administration use

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, connection

I am facing the following situation:

I have several devices (embedded devices running ARCH Linux) and i would like to have administration access to each device at any time. The problem is the devices are behind a NAT, so establishing a connection from a server to a device is not possible. How could i achieve this?

I thought i could write a simple service running on the device that opens a connection to a server at startup. This TCP connection remains open and can be used from the server to administrate the device. But is it a good idea to keep TCP connections open for a long time? If i have a lot of devices, for example 1000, will i have a problem on the server side with 1000 open TCP connections?
Is there maybe another way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is it a good idea to keep TCP connections open for a long time?

It's not necessarily a bad idea; although in practice the connections will fail from time to time (e.g. due to network reconfiguration, temporary network outages, etc), so your clients should contain logic to reconnect automatically when this happens.  Also note that TCP will not usually not detect it when a completely-idle TCP connection no longer has connectivity, so to avoid "zombie connections" that aren't actually connected, you may want to either enable SO_KEEPALIVE, or have your clients and/or server send the (very occasional) bit of dummy data on the socket just to goose the TCP stack into checking whether connectivity still exists on the socket.

> If i have a lot of devices, for example 1000, will i have a problem on the server side with 1000 open TCP connections?

Scaling is definitely an issue you'll need to think about.  For example, select() is typically implemented to only handle up to a fixed number of connections (often 1024), or if your server is using the thread-per-connection model, you'd find that a process with 1000+ threads is not very efficient.  Check out the [c10k problem article](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) for lots of interesting details about various approaches and how well they scale up (or don't).

> Is there maybe another way?

If you don't need immediate access to the clients, you could always have them check in periodically instead (e.g. once every 5 minutes); or you could have them occasionally send a UDP packet to the server instead of keeping a TCP connection all the time, just to let the server know their presence, and have the server indicate to them somehow (e.g. by updating a well-known web page that the clients check from time to time) when it wanted one of them to open a full TCP connection.  Or maybe just use multiple servers to share the load...

Answer (score 1):

The only limit I know of is imposed by state tracking in the `iptables` code.  Check the value of `net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max` on both sides if you're using this to make sure you have enough headroom for other activities.

If you set the socket option `SO_KEEPALIVE` before the `connect()` call, the kernel will send [TCP keepalives](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html) to make sure the far end is still there.  This will mean that connections won't linger forever in the event of a reboot.